# Default home page sort order for unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request

I first joined SO to ask a specific question and so as to not be a leech did my usual habit when joining a forum of checking for any questions I could help with by pressing the unanswered button. After scrolling through half a dozen or so pages without seeing anything I could answer I left it at that for a while.

Since then I've become more active and realise the sort order, but I wonder if maybe "newest" page would make a better default than the current that ranks by votes and almost becomes a "too hard" basket by the nature of older questions gaining more votes over time. Or maybe a new page like "interesting" that throws in a bit of a mix based on age, page views and votes.

Anyway just an idea I thought I'd throw out there for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the Newest tab and it saved that preference until you **clear your cookies/history**. Next time when you click on the Unanswered  page you will see the question sorted via Newest question.

Comment: Thanks Habib, I hadn't spotted that before. Although I was mainly thinking about new users to the site that might do the same as me on their first visit or two before knowing about the other options.

Comment: @PeterJ, I am new to meta, I believe you may re-tag your question with the tag `feature-request`

Comment: thanks I see the tag includes proposals rather than just specific requests so have just retagged.